# eslint Angular Strict Template Checks should show error

Tags: angular, eslint, tslint, nrwl-nx, typescript-eslint

We recently migrated to a new project with many angular 11+ applications and libraries. We have `angularCompilerOptions.strictTemplates: true` set for all the applications.

The problem is that we have a CI pipeline that checks for formatting and runs eslint, but the strict template checks errors do not get flagged until we do a production build. because of this, we have to build all the affected apps in the CI, and if we change a library component all apps need to be checked and built. this can take hours.

**Is there a way that eslint/tslint can check for any strict template errors without needing to build the app every time?**

Here is our eslint.json:

```json
{
  "extends": ["../../.eslintrc.json"],
  "ignorePatterns": ["!**/*"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@nrwl/nx/angular", "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"],
      "parserOptions": { "project": ["apps/to-home/tsconfig.*?.json"] },
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": ["error", { "type": "attribute", "prefix": "toh", "style": "camelCase" }],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": ["error", { "type": "element", "prefix": "toh", "style": "kebab-case" }]
      }
    },
    { "files": ["*.html"], "extends": ["plugin:@nrwl/nx/angular-template"], "rules": {} }
  ]
}
```

and the root json:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": ["**/*"],
  "plugins": ["@nrwl/nx"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx", "*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
          "error",
          {
            "argsIgnorePattern": "^_"
          }
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": [
          "error",
          {
            "allow": ["constructors"]
          }
        ],
        "@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries": [
          "error",
          {
            "enforceBuildableLibDependency": true,
            "allow": [
              "@models/*",
              "@apc-common/**",
              "@apc-directives/**",
              "@apc-helpers/**",
              "@apc-modals/**",
              "@apc-models/**",
              "@apc-pipes/**",
              "@apc-services/**",
              "@apc-store/**",
              "@apc-admin/**",
              "@apc-help/**",
              "@apc-home/**",
              "@apc-materials/**",
              "@apc-materials-deferral-review/**",
              "@apc-parking/**",
              "@apc-report/**",
              "@apc-turnover/**",
              "@apc-wall-display/**",
              "@apc-workload/**"
            ],
            "depConstraints": [
              {
                "sourceTag": "scope:server",
                "onlyDependOnLibsWithTags": ["scope:server", "scope:models"]
              },
              {
                "sourceTag": "scope:ui",
                "onlyDependOnLibsWithTags": ["scope:ui", "scope:shared", "scope:models"]
              },
              {
                "sourceTag": "scope:shared",
                "onlyDependOnLibsWithTags": ["scope:shared", "scope:models"]
              },
              {
                "sourceTag": "scope:models",
                "onlyDependOnLibsWithTags": ["scope:models"]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": [
          "error",
          {
            "allowDestructuring": true,
            "allowedNames": ["self"]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@nrwl/nx/typescript"],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": "./tsconfig.json"
      },
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@nrwl/nx/javascript"],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript strictly typed: strict mode is not enough,
[typescript-strictly-typed](https://github.com/cyrilletuzi/typescript-strictly-typed) enables configurations for `strictly` typed TypeScript, ESLint or TSLint, and optionally Angular. But let’s explain first.

The officially recommended way to work with TypeScript is in [strict mode](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Strict mode is enabled when creating:

1. a TypeScript project (`tsc --init`)
2. an Angular app in strict mode (`ng new --strict`)

Strict mode activates 2 main compiler options:

```
noImplicitAny

strictNullChecks
```

Now, `TypeScript` will ask to tell when a value can be null (`strictNullChecks`), and when inference is not possible it will ask the type (`noImplicitAny`).

The bellow code will compile, even in strict mode: explicit anys are still accepted by TypeScript

```
function test(hello: any, world = '') {
  hello; // any
  world; // string
}
```

`TSLint` has the [no-any](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any/) rule. With ESLint and [@typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/) [no-explicit-any](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md) rule:

***.eslintrc.json***

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error"
  }
}
```

**Angular strict:**
Angular has its own additional strict compiler options:
***tsconfig.json***

```
{
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true
  }
}
```

We only had to run `ng build` to see this error with Angular 9 and upper. while in Angular 8 we did not see this error message when we ran `ng build`.

**Automate configuration**:
Enables configurations for strictly typed `TypeScript`, `ESLint` or `TSLint`, and optionally Angular.
Just run `npx typescript-strictly-typed` in your project.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of template checks, the only way to check the templates that i know of is using the ng build --prod command. How can we check if the template is going to fail before we do a build?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't have enabled aot on development environment.
You may have aot=true only on production section of angular.json.
To set it to all configurations, do this:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "aot": true,
...
```